# Table HTML tag on IOS is blocking the scroll down when it is wider that screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a table that works perfectly in Chrome but once I open it on safari it blocks the scroll down at its level.

It happens on phone size, when screen is smaller that table size.

Then It works with table-layout: fixed; but is makes the table adjust to the screen size.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  th {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SDFSDFSDFSD</th>
      <th>SDFSDFSDF</th>
      <th>SDFSDFSDF</th>
      <th>SDFSDFSDFSDF</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>SDFSDFSDF</td>
      <td>
        DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
      </td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>BSDFSDFSDF_</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDF</td>
      <td>SDFSDFSDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
        <td>SDFSDF</td>
        <td>SDFSDFSDFSDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>SDFSDFSDFSDFSDFSDF</td>
      <td>
        SDFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
      </td>
      <td>1 SDFDSFSDFSDF</td>
      <td>SDFSDFSDFSD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```